Spring Boot: Bean of type could not be found. Consider defining a bean
I know that this question has be asked multiple times and I feel really stupid but I cannot get my Spring Boot REST app to work. I am building a thing for a game I'm playing and I'm trying out Spring Boot for the first time. So this is my app/package structure:
com.findersgame.questtracker
|- FindersGameQuestTrackerApiApplication.java
|
|- controller
|  |- QuestController.java
|
|- model
|  |- Location.java
|  |- Provider.java
|  |- Quest.java
|
|- repository
|  |- LocationRepository.java
|  |- ProviderRepository.java
|  |- QuestRepository.java
|
|- service
   |- QuestService.java

As far as I understand, this is the "correct" way of dividing up controllers, models, repositories, services etc. in Spring Boot.
Moving on to the main file, FindersGameQuestTrackerApiApplication.java:
package com.findersgame.questtracker;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={ "com.findersgame.questtracker.*" })
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.findersgame.questtracker.repository.*")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.findersgame.questtracker.*" })
public class FindersGameQuestTrackerApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FindersGameQuestTrackerApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}

From what I have been able to figure out from googling, searching SO and Reddit I have all the correct interfaces added (@SpringBootApplication, @EnableJpaRepositories and @ComponentScan).
Next there is the controller, service and repositories I have created so far:
package com.findersgame.questtracker.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.findersgame.questtracker.service.QuestService;

@RestController
public class QuestController {
    private QuestService questService;

    public QuestController(QuestService questService) {
        super();
        this.questService = questService;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("fix-quests")
    public void fixQuests() {
        questService.fixQuests();
    }
}

package com.findersgame.questtracker.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.findersgame.questtracker.model.Location;
import com.findersgame.questtracker.model.Provider;
import com.findersgame.questtracker.model.Quest;
import com.findersgame.questtracker.repository.LocationRepository;
import com.findersgame.questtracker.repository.ProviderRepository;
import com.findersgame.questtracker.repository.QuestRepository;

@Service
public class QuestService {
    
    @Autowired
    private LocationRepository locationRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private ProviderRepository providerRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private QuestRepository questRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    public QuestServiceImpl(
            FlooRepository flooRepository,
            GiverRepository giverRepository,
            QuestRepository questRepository) {

        super();
        this.flooRepository = flooRepository;
        this.giverRepository = giverRepository;
        this.questRepository = questRepository;
    }

    public void fixQuests() {
        List<Quest> quests = questRepository.findAll();
        
        quests.forEach(quest -> {
            String locationName = quest.getLocationName();
            String providerName = quest.getProviderName();
            
            if (locationName != null) {
                Location location = locationRepository.findByName(locationName);
                
                if (location != null) {
                    quest.setLocationId(location.getId());
                }
            }
            
            if (providerName != null) {
                Provider provider = providerRepository.findByName(providerName);
                
                if (provider != null) {
                    quest.setLocationId(provider.getId());
                }
            }
            
            questRepository.save(quest);
        });
    }
}

package com.findersgame.questtracker.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.findersgame.questtracker.model.Location;

@Repository
public interface LocationRepository extends JpaRepository<Location, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE `name` = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    Location findByName(String name);
}

package com.findersgame.questtracker.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.findersgame.questtracker.model.Provider;

@Repository
public interface ProviderRepository extends JpaRepository<Provider, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM providers WHERE `name` = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    Provider findByName(String name);
}

package com.findersgame.questtracker.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.findersgame.questtracker.model.Quest;

@Repository
public interface QuestRepository extends JpaRepository<Quest, Long> {
    //pass
}

The models I have so far:

Questhas id, locationId,  locationName, providerId, providerName and name.
Both Location and Provider only has id and name so far.
All of the above have getters and setters.

My problem is that I get the following message:
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.findersgame.questtracker.service.QuestService required a bean of type 'com.findersgame.questtracker.repository.LocationRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.findersgame.questtracker.repository.LocationRepository' in your configuration.

From my searching around the web I encountered the following:

Add @EnableJpaRepositories to he main class, did that.
Add @ComponentScan to the main class, did that.
Add @EnableJpaRepositories to the main class, did that.
Add @Service to the service and @Repository to the repositories, but I had that from the beginning.

Also tried without @Repository since it should not be needed (already part of JpaRepository).


Tried with and without @Autowired before the attributes and the constructor in the service.
I also tried removing LocationRepository and ProviderRepository entirely to make sure that the queries I wrote didn't affect it or that having multiple services didn't affect it.

The only difference was that not it couldn't find QuestRepository instead.



None of what I have tried so far has been working. I am sure I am missing something simple but from all my searching I have not been able to find it. Please help!

No need to define ComponentScan and EnableJpaRepos manually.
All classes are scanned that are in any sub-package of the package the Application is in

remove the .* at the end of the @EnableJpaRepositories("com.findersgame.questtracker.repository.*") and it should work

share your model class. did you apply @Entity Annotation?

Removing the .* seems to have worked. Thanks a lot!

Ditch @ComponentScan, @EnableJpaRepositories and remove basePackages neither of those is needed. You don't need those @Autowired annotations either (it will automatically detect the constructor). The @Repository isn't adding anything as well. Regarding "the correct way" that is opiniated and imho it is the wrong way to package things, you should place things that belong together in the same package (functional) yours is a technical separation.

You stated all the structures correctly, but the more basic implementation is that you create an interface named QuestService and then add a service named QuestServiceImpl that implements QuestService . You must specify the type of injection and inject it in your constructor.**
@Service
public class QuestServiceImpl implements QuestService {

    @Autowired
    private LocationRepository locationRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ProviderRepository providerRepository;

    @Autowired
    private QuestRepository questRepository;

    public QuestServiceImpl(LocationRepository locationRepository,
                            ProviderRepository providerRepository,
                            QuestRepository questRepository) {
        this.locationRepository = locationRepository;
        this.providerRepository = providerRepository;
        this.questRepository = questRepository;
    }

    public void fixQuests() {
        List<Quest> quests = questRepository.findAll();
        quests.forEach(quest -> {
            String locationName = quest.getLocationName();
            String providerName = quest.getProviderName();
            if (locationName != null) {
                Location location = locationRepository.findByName(locationName);
                if (location != null) {
                    quest.setLocationId(location.getId());
                }
            }
            if (providerName != null) {
                Provider provider = providerRepository.findByName(providerName);
                if (provider != null) {
                    quest.setLocationId(provider.getId());
                }
            }
            questRepository.save(quest);
        });
    }
}


@Autowired doesn't add anything as DI is done through the constructor.

I think the issue with your configuration is that the * wildcard shouldn't be used in the @scanBasePackages, @EnableJpaRepositories, or @ComponentScan attributes. These annotations expect fully qualified package names, and the wildcard is not necessary when defining base packages.
Here's how you can modify your configuration:
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages ="com.findersgame.questtracker")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.findersgame.questtracker.repository")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.findersgame.questtracker")
public class QuestTrackerApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(QuestTrackerApplication.class, args);
}
}

You can check also this question: @EnableJpaRepositories looking for which package?
